# Make wordpress join default user metas with a column from another table while displaying the wp_users table on the users screen

Tags: plugin-development, filters

I am creating a plugin that adds a custom sortable column(Reputation Score) to the users table displayed at admin page > users, the problem is the column's data should be fetched from a MySQL table wp_user_reputation (`userid`,`user_reputation_score`) [created for our own purpose].

My assessment is that I  would need the column to be present
in query so that I can add sorting capability for it. How do I make make WordPress to join the wp_users table with wp_user_reputation.

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid a second query just for sorting you could use the `pre_user_query` hook to support a custom `orderby` value.

This code will enable sorting users by reputation in a single query just by setting `orderby` to `reputation`.

```
function wpse_296999_pre_user_query( $user_query ) {
    global $wpdb;

    $order = $user_query->query_vars['order'];
    $orderby = $user_query->query_vars['orderby'];

    // If orderby is 'reputation'.
    if ( 'reputation' === $orderby ) {
        // Join reputation table.
        $user_search->query_from .= " INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}user_reputation AS reputation ON {$wpdb->users}.ID = reputation.userid"; 
        // And order by it.
        $user_search->query_orderby = " ORDER BY reputation.user_reputation_score $order";
    } 
}
add_action('pre_user_query','wpse_27518_pre_user_query');
```

Just make sure that on this line:

```
if ( 'reputation' === $orderby ) {
```

`'reputation'` is whatever the actual name of your sortable column is.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to construct a custom MySQL-query to retrieve the sorted `userid` from your `wp_user_reputation` table. Then you could use the sorted `userid`s to construct a [`get_users()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users) query with `'include' => $your_retrieved_ids` and `'order' => 'include'`.